# how to show count of each category list rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following view to show the categories with the count

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
<% category.sub_categories.sort.each do |sub_category| %>
    <li><%= link_to sub_category.name, "category/#{sub_category.slug}", title: sub_category.name.capitalize %> <%= sub_category.posts.where(status: 1).count %></li>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

But I dont think using `where` in view is not good idea. Is there any other way to perform such operation.

I am getting correct count but I need better way to do this. can anyone help

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average

Comment: @NitinJ This is ok from the above doc `Person.count(:age)` but how can I get the count of persons with age 21.

Comment: Person.group(:age).count(21)

Comment: if you want to make it clearer, you can create a method or a scope on the 'sub_category' class like `#active_post_count`

Comment: `result = Person.group(:age).count` will return something like {21=>12, 22=>7, 23=>4, 24=>39} so for which age you want to take it out just do result[age] where age is a number given by you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Post` model should have a scope on it that encapsulates this status logic:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.active
    where(status: 1)
  end
end
```

Then call it like so from the view:

```
sub_category.posts.active.count
```

Comment: and if you use many times that, put that calls in a method. `def active_post_count; self.active.posts.count; end`

Answer (score 0):

use scope to do the same thing, your solution is ok otherwise. you don't need to do this controller.

```
scope :active_posts, lambda{ where(status: 1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see with this is it causes N+1 queries, because you do 1 query for the categories THEN another query for EACH category. This is ok with small quantities, however can cause serious performance problems later on.

1) I recommend you look into "counter_cache"ing:
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

2) OR upon activation/deactivation of Posts, create a method that will increment/decrement a attribute on the Post's Category (i.e. "active_posts")